# Fetching data within jsonarray

Tags: android

I have a Json array which contains another array. I want to fetch the data of second array.ie: In my case "Material code". Please forgive me if I asked a repeated question.

**My Json**

```
{
"Result": true,
"Records": {
    "ID": "37e33c9e",
    "RRNo": "RR301",
    "Title": "rightnow",
    "RRDate": "2018-06-27T00:00:00",
    "RRForCompany": "A",
    "RRStatus": "Open",
    "RRDetailList": [{
        "ID": "dff49a5a",
        "RRID": "37e33c9e",
        "MaterialID": "b4378594",
        "Description": "Pol",
        "ExtendedDescription": "hello",
        "CurrStock": "10",
        "ApRate": 2000.00,
        "RequestedQty": "8100",
        "RRMaterialObj": {
            "ID": "b4378594",
            "MaterialCode": "R101",
            "ApRate": 0.0,
        }
    }],
    "CompanyObj": null,
    "CommonObj": {

    },
    "RRFormatted": "27-Jun-2018",

}
```

}

**What i have done**

```
                ArrayList<String[]> dataArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonObject1= records.getJSONArray("RRDetailList");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject1.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject(i);
                    String[] data = new String[6];
                    data[0] = jsonObject2.getString("ID");
                    data[1] = jsonObject2.getString("Description");
                    data[2] = jsonObject2.getString("RequestedQty");
                    data[3] = jsonObject2.getString("CurrStock");
                    data[4] = jsonObject2.getString("ApRate");

                    JSONArray jsonObject3 = records.getJSONArray("RRMaterialObj"); 
                    for(int j=0;j<jsonObject3.length();j++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject5= jsonObject3.getJSONObject(j);
                        data[5] =jsonObject5.getString("MaterialCode");
                    }
                    dataArrayList.add(data);
                }
```

Help me. Iam newbie to android.

Comment: `RRMaterialObj` is not an array ... it is also not child of `Records` but child of element in `RRDetailList` ... it is not about being newbie but simple logic

Comment: @Selvin yes bro..You are right

Comment: @AndroDevil you can check my updated answer..

Comment: @GowthamanM ok bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `records.getJSONArray("RRMaterialObj")`
>
> **change into**
>
> ```
> `jsonObject2.getJSONObject("RRMaterialObj");`
> ```

```
 JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("RRMaterialObj"); 

 data[5] =jsonObject3.getString("MaterialCode");
```

Comment: `RRMaterialObj` is not an array-it is an object, i guess

Comment: @NavneetKrishna sry i mis understand.i edited my answer.. yes thanks

Comment: @GowthamanM thanks bro...